# How to display two different message boxes when fields are incorrect in text boxes

Tags: c#, sql

I need to display a message for two different `textBoxes` in my app if the information is entered incorrectly.

Basically when the user enters the information it will then search the database to check if that info is there.  If it is not then it must display a message saying the entered information is incorrect

This is my code I am using

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DEVELOPMENT\ACCESSCONTROL;Initial Catalog=ACCESSCONTROL;User ID=sa;Password=P@55w0rd123");
SqlCommand check_User_Name = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM NewVisitor WHERE (IDNumber = @IDNumber AND PersonVisit = @PersonVisit)", con);
check_User_Name.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDNumber", idNumber_TxtBox.Text);
check_User_Name.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonVisit", personVisiting_TxtBox.Text);
con.Open();

int UserExist = (int)check_User_Name.ExecuteScalar();

if (UserExist > 0)
{
      .....
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No Visitor with ID Number: " + idNumber_TxtBox.Text + " Exists");

    MessageBox.Show("No Employee,  " + personVisiting_TxtBox.Text + " Exists");
}
```

At the moment it will only display the first `messageBox` if either information is entered incorrectly

Comment: Then you need two checks I guess.

Comment: MessageBox.Show is modal. In other words, you need to close that message box before seeing the next message box

Comment: If the user must enter a valid `IDNumber` **and** a valid `PersonVisit`, then I would use only 1 message such as `Invalid ID Number or Employee`

Comment: You can always append each message together and display them in a list like fashion on one MessageBox.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to write different messages if the missing user is caused by a wrong ID o by a wrong PersonVisit value?

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine the two messages into a single string.  Oh, and don't contatenate strings with a +, use string.Format or string interpolation ($)

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine($"No Visitor with ID Number: {idNumber_TxtBox.Text} Exists");
sb.AppendLine($"No Employee, {personVisiting_TxtBox.Text} Exists");
MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to show two Message Boxes at the same time since the Message Box is a [Modal window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window). So it will stop the execution of the MainWindow untill that first message box window is closed.

You could handle that by using a single message box with a combination of both messages.

```cs
string errorMessage = $"No Visitor with ID Number: {idNumber_TxtBox.Text} Exists") + Environment.NewLine + $"No Employee, {personVisiting_TxtBox.Text} Exists");
MessageBox.Show(errorMessage);
```